# Function has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022 if I try to call a function of a simple struct in the Watch window then I get "Function has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations" error. And if I call a template function in the Watch window, then I get this error: class "MyStruct" has no member "Multi". If I use these functions one time in the source code, then they will also begin to work in the Watch window, but how to make them work in the Watch window without having to use them in the source code?

My code:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int i;
    MyStruct(int _i) : i{ _i } {}
    int Add(int x) { return i + x; };

    template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp Multi(int x)
    {
        return (_Tp)i * x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct s1(2);
    //auto x1 = s1.Add(5);
    //auto x2 = s1.Multi<double>(9);

    return 0;
}
```

And the Watch window:
[image]

I am running the Debug version.
Linker-> Debugging-> Generate Debug Info is set to "/DEBUG:FULL" and optimizations are disabled: Disabled (/Od).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how to make them work in the Watch window without having to use them in the source code

You can't. C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level. A template is not a function. There's no code in there. It is a template for a function, in the most literal sense, by definition and name. In other words it's just a blueprint, of sorts, for an actual function.

When code references a template, and provides the template's parameters (explicitly, or via template argument deduction), only then you end up with an actual, honest-to-goodness function. With actual code. This process is called ***template instantiation***.

And until a template function gets instantiated, it literally does not exist as part of the program, and there's nothing for the debugger to call. The debugger can search high and low, but it won't find anything it can actually invoke. It does not exist. But when a template gets instantiated, as part of actual code, the debugger can find its munged symbol in the program's symbol table, referencing an actual function, and call it.

Now, theoretically, it would be possible for a debugger to either include a C++ compiler as part of the debugger itself, or use the external C++ compiler, to, somehow, instantiate the template into an actual function and call it. But, practically, it is unlikely that there's some debugger, out there, that actually works like that.

Comment: In this case, I would use the word "stencil", as in an artist's stencil.  I found that *stencil* is sometimes less confusing. :-)